# Cakephp display data mysql at default.ctp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to display a few items from MySQL in a Page (View/Layouts/default.ctp) that is called from Content.php (View/Pages/Items.ctp)

how could I do that?

Comment: What is the name of the model/database table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the name is of the table that you use. 
You can use the simple code in the controller. (`PagesController.php`)

```
$this->set('data', $this->Model->find('all'));  
// change Model for the name of your model.
```

If the model is not automaticly loaded by Cakephp. 
You need to set this in the function of the samecontroller of above.

```
$this->loadModel('Model'); // change Model for the name of your model.
```

In the view (`Items.ctp`):

```
foreach($data as $d){
   echo $d['Model']['name'];
   // change Model for the name of your model.
}
```

Also read **[Cakephp Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)**

Comment: Ok, that worked well: I put $this->set at ItemsController.php, created Model Items and a view Items, so, how could I call this set at a Layouts/Pages and display Model Data?

Comment: You could try it to set in de `AppController` because every controller  calls the `AppController`.

Comment: like this: `class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
 $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all'));  
}`?, and at home.ctp: `foreach( $users as $user ){ ?>
<p>ID: <?php echo $user['User']['id'] ?>
<?php } ?>` ? didn't work, gives me this:  Error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION at $this->set

Comment: No in the ` public function beforeFilter() { }` the view is good like that.

Comment: at `foreach($users as $user){` gives Undefined variable: users [APP\View\Pages\home.ctp, line 5].

Comment: `class AppController extends Controller { public function beforeFilter() { $this->loadModel('User'); $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all')); } }` doesn't work ?

Comment: Yeah, that works! but.. it will become slow, won't? because every single page i access he will call this..

Comment: No because you dont call the data in every view (page).. so no problem.